# Why does this error occur when my text files have clearly more than 1 lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a beginner in Python. I've checked my text files, and definitely have more than 1 lines, so I don't understand why it gave me the error on

```
---> 11     Coachid.append(split[1].rstrip())
  

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: "definitely have more than 1 lines" - do they also have more than 1 columns? `split=line.split(",")` is a list of columns in the current line.

Comment: @ForceBru yes more then 1 columns

Comment: Well, apparently not. You can print each line and see which one triggers the error.

Comment: The lines that trigger the erros is this 11 Coachid.append(split[1].rstrip())

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was talking about the line in your text file.

Comment: Ok i wasnt quite get what you mean by printing each line, can you explain it to me more detailly or provide a code for me to understand. Thank you

Comment: For instance, you can replace `split=line.split(",")` with `print(line); split=line.split(",")` to print each line. When the error occurs, the code will stop and the last line printed will be the one that caused the error.

Comment: @ForceBru I understand now thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are the lines:

```
split=line.split(",")
Coachname.append(split[0].rstrip())
Coachid.append(split[1].rstrip())
```

The first line assumes that `line` contains at lest one comma so that after method `split` is called variable `split` will be a list of at least length two. But if `line` contains no commas, then `split` will have length 1 and `Coachid.append(split[1].rstrip())` will generate the error you are getting. You need to add some conditional tests of the length of `split`.

**Update**

Your code should look like (assuming that the correct action is to append an empty string to the `Coachid` list if it is missing from the input):

```
split=line.split(",")
split_length = len(split)
Coachname.append(split[0].rstrip())
# append '' if split_length is less than 2:
Coachid.append('' if split_length < 2 else split[1].rstrip())
etc. for the other fields
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, may i know how can i tests the length of split?

Comment: So basically everyline with a comma is = split length 1 right?

Comment: Thank you it helps,  now i faced a new problem on displaying the records, is there a way to display every single records accordingly for example coachname, coach id, sports, wages, performance? Because when i print, the whole coachname prints as a list, then the other follows as the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop over lines of a file, you have to use

```py
for line in f.readlines()
    ...
```

Comment: Not necessarily. `for line in f` also loops over the lines.